# Is it possible to make the jquery datepicker always visible in a form?

Tags: 8, forms, javascript, datetime

I'd like to have the jquery datepicker calendar always visible on a date element in my Drupal 8 form.

[I see that this is possible to do by setting the datepicker to a div instead of an input.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4188452/5306408)

However, since date elements of forms are declared like

```
$form['date'] = array(
    '#type' => 'date',
);
```

[this doesn't seem like an option that the date element properties allow.](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21Element%21Date.php/class/Date/8.2.x)

Is there a method of doing this that is compatible with Drupal forms?

Comment: Try using `'#type' => 'date_popup',` as per [Using with date_popup Form API element](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/modules/date-popup-timepicker/using-with-date_popup-form-api-element). This worked for me in D7, hopefully it still works in D8.

Comment: @NoSssweat thanks for the suggestion! unfortunately, it does not seem to work in D8 :(

Comment: The default datepicker is using the HTML5 datepicker element. If you want to use jQuery's datepicker, you would have to implement attaching this to your form. Would that be an option for you?